# Dynamic method creation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dynamic

In the book [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer), the authors suggest that all method inputs should be validated.  This allows problems with a method to be caught early and their sources traced easily.

In my Mac application, I accomplished this by creating an `Assert` class.  This class has several class methods.  These methods determine if some precondition is met, and if it is not, then an exception is thrown.  A typical assertion might looks something like this:

```
-(void) setWidth: (int) theWidth {
    [Assert integer: width isGreaterThanInteger: 0];
    width = theWidth;
}
```

This works really well, and significantly reduced the amount of time I've spend bug hunting.  However, I've noticed lately some of the assertion methods are very useful as predicates.  For example, my `integer:isGreaterThanInteger:andLessThanInteger:` and my `stringIsNotEmpty:` methods are equally useful.  To this end, I created a second class `Predicate`, which I filled with several of my more useful predicate methods.  So I took the logic from the assert methods, and moved it into `Predicate`, and then rewrote my `Assert` methods like the following:

```
if ![Predicate predicateMethod]
    throw exception
```

This has turned into a maintenance nightmare.  If I change the name of a method name in `Predicate`, I must also change it in `Assert` to stay consistent.  If I update the documentation of an `Assert` method, then I must do the same to a `Predicate` method.

Ideally, I would like the reconstruct the `Assert` class so that when any method is called on it, it intercepts the selector.  The `Predicate` class can then be checked to see if it responds to the selector, and if it does, the method is called on `Predicate`with the same arguments that were passed into the `Assert` method.  If the `Predicate` method returns false, then an exception is thrown.

Is there a way to do this in Objective-C?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, and not an answer, but what is the advantage of your `integer:isGreaterThanInteger:` above, say, `[Assert condition: width > 0];`, i.e. `+ (void) condition: (BOOL) condition;`?

Comment: The main reason I did it this way is now I have an pre-made method to pass around as an argument should I ever need it.  For example, I could create a Heap class which took in a selector argument. I could pass in `integer:isGreaterThanInteger:` if I wanted a max-heap and `integer:isLessThanInteger:` if I wanted a min-heap.  Admittedly, having these methods also fills out the predicate class, and you could accomplish this purpose just as easily by passing around a block, but it's something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overriding `resolveClassMethod:`.  While overriding `forwardInvocation` might have worked (I would have had to figure out some way to override it for the class object), `resolveClassMethod:` seems like it's the easier and more efficient method.  Here's what my final implementation ended up looking like:

```
#import "Assert.h"
#import "Predicate.h"
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>

void handlePredicateSelector(id self, SEL _cmd, ...);

@implementation Assert

+(void) failWithMessage: (NSString *) message
{
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
    [NSException raise:@"ASSERTION FAILURE" format:message];
}

+(void) fail
{
    [Assert failWithMessage:@"An unconditional failure has been detected."];
}

+(BOOL) resolveClassMethod: (SEL) selector
{
    if ([(id) [Predicate class] respondsToSelector:selector])
    {
        /*
         The meta class fix was taken from here: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/08/dynamically-adding-class-objects.html
         */

        //get the method properties from the Predicate class
        Class predicateMetaClass = objc_getMetaClass([[Predicate className] UTF8String]);
        Method predicateMethod = class_getClassMethod(predicateMetaClass, selector);
        const char *encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(predicateMethod);

        Class selfMetaClass = objc_getMetaClass([[self className] UTF8String]);
        class_addMethod(selfMetaClass, selector, (IMP) handlePredicateSelector, "B@:?");

        return YES;
    }
    return [super resolveClassMethod:selector];
}

@end

void handlePredicateSelector(id self, SEL _cmd, ...)
{
    //get the number of arguments minus the self and _cmd arguments
    NSMethodSignature *predicateMethodSignature = [(id) [Predicate class] methodSignatureForSelector:_cmd];
    NSUInteger numberOfArguments = [predicateMethodSignature numberOfArguments] - 2;

    NSInvocation *predicateInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:predicateMethodSignature];
    [predicateInvocation setTarget:[Predicate class]];
    [predicateInvocation setSelector:_cmd];

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, _cmd);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArguments; i++)
    {
        void *arg = va_arg(ap, void *);
        [predicateInvocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:i+2];
    }

    va_end(ap);

    BOOL returnValue;
    [predicateInvocation invoke];
    [predicateInvocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];

    //determine if the assertion is true
    if (!returnValue)
    {
        [Assert failWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"The following assertion failed: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]];
    }
}
```

The only thing I couldn't really figure out was how to get the type encoding from the method signature.  It didn't seem to affect the output of the methods, but I would like to fix it if I can.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`-forwardingTargetForSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector%3a) to simply forward the method to another object, but if you want advanced behavior (like checking the return value to see if it's false), you may need to use [`-forwardInvocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardInvocation%3a). (However, note that the documentation says this is "much more expensive" than the former option.)

Comment: Can these be used with class methods?

Comment: Hm, good question. I think they probably can, perhaps if you use `+forwardInvocation:`. Curiously, the documentation doesn't seem to mention it. Try it and see :)

Comment: Also see [this post](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html) for some more detail and techniques on forwarding.

Comment: try implementing forwardingTargetForSelector: as a class method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pure Objective-C, you should see the "Forwarding" discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C).  It basically describes how to do exactly what you want, including example code.

If you're using Cocoa then you might have to use [forwardInvocation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardInvocation%3a) instead.