# Suppressing Class Method Not Found Warnings in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a class whose methods are determined at runtime, as indicated in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185122/dynamic-method-creation-in-objective-c).  This works great, but now I have a bunch of warnings that look like the following littering my code:

```
Class method '+objectIsNotNil:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

While these warnings don't actually affect the build process, they're very annoying and make it harder to spot relevant warnings.  Is there some way to disable them, but only for the `Assert` class (maybe some kind of macro)?  If this isn't possible, then is there some way to turn them off for the entire build?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One alternative would be to use performSelector:withObject: instead of the direct method call. 
So instead of:

```
[Assert objectIsNotNil:object];
```

You could have:

```
[Assert performSelector:@selector(objectIsNotNil:) withObject:object];
```

It does not look quite as nice but it will remove the warnings. Furthermore, this pattern will work for any selector you want. To make things look a little better you could use macros in the following way:

```
#define ASSERT_PRECONDITION(sel, obj)  [Assert performSelector:@selector(sel) withObject:obj]
```

This way your assert would look like this:

```
ASSERT_PRECONDITION(objectIsNotNil:, object);
```

Comment: I really like this solution.  It doesn't require me to use any compiler flags because it doesn't use any warnings.  Plus, the macro gets rid of some of the ugliness, which is helpful.  My only issue with it is that using `performSelector:` only lets you use two arguments at most, and these arguments must be objects.  I'll probably use `objc_msgSend' instead, since it gets rid of those limitations.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

these cases should be extremely rare...

I've declared a hidden protocol which declared the methods with proper signatures. 'Hidden' in the sense that it was only included by the translations which needed them.

```
@protocol MONRuntimeClassInterface
+ (BOOL)objectIsNotNil:(id)object;
@end
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, but it really kind of ruins my original solution to the problem of code duplication.  What I'm really looking for is some way to surpress the warning.

Comment: @helixed since objc is a c family language, you should correct these warnings. when the compiler does not know the class/instance method's signature, it assumes every arg and return type is `id`. the compiler does many nice things for you when passing and returning arguments - promotions, conversions, adjusts alignment, and so on. the same thing plagued c programmers with implicit declarations. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  you should consider deviations of this formula (e.g. passing or returning a non-object) to be undefined behavior. to disable this check, you could use `GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR = YES` -- but i strongly discourage disabling that. there are better ways to solve this problem. good luck

Comment: I know what the compiler does.  What I'm saying is I have a valid reason for ignoring these warnings.  The methods I'm calling are being added to the object, its just being done at runtime instead of at compile time.

Comment: And setting `GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR` to no didn't make the warning go away.

Comment: it will if you use `@selector(objectIsNotNil:)`. good luck.

Comment: +1, this is the right answer. If you're calling a method directly, it must be declared.

Comment: @Anomie I don't believe you're correct.  Have you taken a look at the link I posted in my question?  The method doesn't have to be declared to call it and there's a good use case for not declaring it.

Comment: @helixed: Believe whatever you want, but if you're returning anything other than `id` you may run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy answer:**

You don't want to do this. And if I understand your problem right, you don't need to. You're defining all the relevant methods in your Predicate class described in the link and Assertion is just forwarding to them. Including Predicate.h and making sure everything's declared in the interface should work fine. Like methods called on objects typed `id`, the compiler will consider methods called on a `Class` object to be found so long as it knows of at least one class in that compilation unit that implements a class method with the same name.

**Alternative answer:**

If you really want to suppress compiler warnings, for example if you're calling a method that don't exist *anywhere* at compile-time then you need to use either NSObject's `performSelector:` method or the runtime function `objc_msgSend()`. This won't be checked for a matching method at compile time. However, for some C types which you could plausibly want to pass as arguments (floats and certain larger structs), the compiler *needs* to know their type. In the absence of a method definition, it needs information from you. `performSelector:` works by only accepting objects of type id. `objc_msgSend` needs casting casted to a function with the appropriate signature before it's called (and in some cases, replacing with a variant function). Mike Ash has a good explanation of how this works [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-20-objective-c-messaging).